# override toString function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, overriding

hi im trying to override default Number wrapper toString function

```js
(function() {
  let _toString = Number.prototype.toString;
  Number.prototype.toString = function() {
    console.log("Number ToString Called");
    _toString();
  };
})();

let b = new Number(5);
console.log(b);
document.writeln(typeof b);
document.writeln(b.toString());
```

I used above code but it gives me error when I try to call original method after console.log()

> Uncaught TypeError: Number.prototype.toString requires that 'this' be
> a Number
> at toString ()
> at Number.toString

I'm looking for ways to do this in javascript
thanks in advance

Comment: try `Function.apply` or `Function.call`.

Comment: and also `return` the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toString` is a method, it receives the object to convert as its `this` context. You need to pass that along to the original function.

`Number.prototype.toString()` can take an optional `radix` argument. You should pass that along as well.

You can call a function with a specific `this` context and arguments by using `Function.prototype.apply`.

You also need to return the value returned by the original function.

```js
(function() {
  let _toString = Number.prototype.toString;
  Number.prototype.toString = function(...args) {
    console.log("Number ToString Called");
    return _toString.apply(this, args);
  };
})();

let b = new Number(20);
console.log(b);
document.writeln(typeof b);
document.writeln(b.toString());
document.writeln(b.toString(8));
```

Comment: what is the reason that we cant use normal _toString()?

Comment: i do the same for window.print function and it works well. but for toString no ( maybe it is prototype)

Comment: How will it know what object to convert?

Comment: `window.print()` doesn't operate on a specific object, it always prints the window.

Answer (score 2):

```js
(function() {
  let _toString = Number.prototype.toString;
  Number.prototype.toString = function() {
    console.log("Number ToString Called");
    return _toString.call(this);// Set the this on which to apply toString & return it
  };
})();

let b = new Number(5);
console.log(b);
document.writeln(typeof b);
document.writeln(b.toString());
```